# Is 15 MB RAM acceptable?

Tags: memory, memory-management, ram

I am writing an application in Python that functions as a daemon, and performs a relatively trivial task in the background. By trivial I mean it waits for keystrokes and plays certain sounds when detected.

I am getting around 15 MB of RAM usage for the python process. Would you consider this acceptable for a small application? It has very low CPU usage.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you can bring it down, do it. No matter what. But if you can't see anything that needs fixing and you're working on a modern system it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: 15MB is nothing in today's terms.

Comment: Thank you, I'll keep this in mind!

Comment: Also, check that the reported 15Mb is actually accurate. Programs tend to need more memory when they're first starting, and if the OS has plenty of resources available it may not try to recover them straight away (if at all).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

15Mb for such a small app is too much. If you can bring it down by changing the source code, you should.

However, it's possible that Python by itself has some fixed overhead. Whether you are OK with paying that cost just to get the Python language for something so simple, is up to you. But in my opinion it might not be worth it and I'd consider different platform for this scenario.

Note that this is not to say that there's anything inherently wrong with Python; there are scenarios where such an overhead might be acceptable cost compared to the benefits and simplicity of language and the ease of implementing complex scenarios with it.

All I am saying is - use the right tool for the task; Python might not be the right one for *this* task.

Comment: Yes, I'll see if I can optimize it further. I don't think using another language would be preferable, since Python has all the libraries I need.